# Using `stripe-node` types in client Angular TypeScript application

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, stripe-payments

Stripe recently added typings to their stripe-node library with version 8. This replaced the need for the separate @types/stripe from DefinitelyTyped. In a node TypeScript environment using these types is straightforward, but I'm wondering if it's feasible to make use of these types in a client-side TypeScript application (Angular) that compiles to browser JavaScript.

It seems to work to `npm install --save stripe` and `import Stripe from 'stripe'` wherever I want to add Stripe typings, but with this being a node library I want to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious. Is there any concern with importing a library designed for node in a client application?

**EDIT:**

To be clear, I am not asking if it's ok to make full use of `stripe-node` in my client. That would be a huge security risk. Now that the library has typings built-in, it would be nice if we could reference those types in client-side typescript.

Answer (score 2):

The types for stripe-node won't work for Stripe.js, you'll want to use these instead: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js

`npm install @stripe/stripe-js`

See this bit about TypeScript support: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#typescript-support

Comment: I am building out the type structure for some response data, and one of the responses is a list of stripe invoices and I'd like to use the `Stripe.Invoice` type from `stripe-node`. Such a type does not exist in `stripe-js`.

Comment: That feature would also not exist in Stripe.js, it would only exist in stripe-node. Can you share more about what you're building? Stripe.js is only for client side interaction which doesn't support listing invoices for example, you'd need to use stripe-node or another server language for that.

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner. I have an API endpoint that returns invoices from stripe for a given customer. It would be nice if on my client I could reference the Invoices type provided by this library, because that's exactly what's getting returned in the response. All of the stripe-node functionality is handled server-side, but it would be nice if on my client I could reference the Invoices type provided by this library, because that's exactly what's getting returned in the response

Answer (score 1):

Concerns would be there, only if you use your **server secret** in your frontend code. As far as you are not doing that & using server library just for the type definitions in frontend, **There is no issue at all.**

Comment: I fully understand why you should not use stripe-node on a client app. I am strictly asking about the types provided as part of the library. For example, I have an API endpoint that returns invoices from stripe for a given customer. It would be nice if on my client I could reference the `Invoices` type provided by this library, because that's exactly what's getting returned in the response.

Answer (score 1):

I use a monorepo package to export the TypeScript interfaces from the `stripe-node` library.

```sh
project
└── packages
    ├── common
    └── web
```

- Prevents clashing with `Stripe` from `@stripe/stripe-js`
- Avoids adding `stripe-node` to `web`, which could be used in a bad way (e.g. using secrets)
- Allows extending types when stripe API calls are made with `expand`

```
// project/packages/common/stripe.ts
import { Stripe } from "stripe";

type StripeInvoice = Stripe.Invoice;
type StripeSubscription = Stripe.Subscription;
type StripeSubscriptionList = Stripe.Response<
  Stripe.ApiList<Stripe.Subscription>
>;
type StripeCustomer = Stripe.Customer;

export {
  StripeInvoice,
  StripeCustomer,
  StripeSubscription,
  StripeSubscriptionList,
};
```

```
// project/packages/web/request.ts
import { StripeSubscriptionList } from "@project/common/stripe";

const listSubscriptions = async () => {
  // Wrapper function for the fetch API
  return await fetchAPI<StripeSubscriptionList>("subscriptions", {
    method: "GET",
  });
};
```